# How to display bool as checkbox list and search by it?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a DB/model field that has a nullable bool type (it is boolean, but can be null). There is no problem to display it in `ActiveForm` or `GridView` as a single field and to make search by it:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['is_manager' => $this->is_manager,]);
```

But how to display it in `ActiveForm` to make search **in LIST** of elements in case when it must be shown as two checkboxes? Example:

[image]

As a result, client can choose options :

- user is a manager
- user is not a manager
- Both
- None of them

UPD: I'll try to explain: it's a search by **LIST** of users, **NOT** by one user. So result can contain both of options, e.g. user 1 is manager, user 2 - is not a manager. If I check two checkboxes - result will show both of them. If check one of them - result will show one of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190877/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-mishin-how-to-display-bool-as-checkbox-list-and). If asked for additional information, please be sure to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the result:

---

In main model I created a virtual property:

```
public $isManagerArray = [];
```

In a `SearchModel` I added a rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['isManagerArray', 'in', 'range' => [true, false]],
    ];
}
```

In `search` method I added a condition:

```
public function search($params) {
    ....

    if (count($this->isManagerArray) > 1) {
        $query->where(['AND',['OR',[ 'is_manager' => true],['is_manager' => false]]]);
    } else if (count($this->isManagerArray) > 0) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([ 'is_manager' => $this->isManagerArray[0] ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

and my `_search.php` view file has:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= Html::checkboxList($model->formName().'[isManagerArray]', null, [1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No']); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

---

If there's a better solution - please share it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reaction, I had to leave for a while. Ok, you're right, four possible answers do make sense in the case of searching. As I see it, in that case, both check boxes represent one boolean. Let's call them, `is_manager` and `is_not_manager`. If the boolean is `false` no filter is applied, otherwise it is. In PHP code:

```
if ($this->is_manager) $query->andFilterWhere(['is_manager' => 'true']);
if ($this->is_not_manager) $query->andFilterWhere(['is_manager' => 'false']);
```

The assumption here is that `$this->is_manager` and `$this->is_not_manager` represent the two booleans from the checkboxes.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I decided to make a virtual property and work with it https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396113/6138795

Answer (score 0):

As commented earlier:
The only I can think of are 3 states (in real life): 
A person is:

1. Not a manager (NO)
2. A manager (YES)
3. Not determined (NULL)

For searching it CAN be handy to have the option for "Doesn't matter me".

I would suggest a dropdown for displaying this in the search form:

- Yes (value "1")
- No  (value "0")
- Undetermined  (value "NULL")
- Doesn't Matter (value "")

In your php you convert these search options to compare your field to respectively 1, 0, null and no comparison in case of "doesn't matter".
I'm assuming a nullable tinyint(1) in your database for the a field `is_manager`.